# LWJGL3. A strange graphic artifact of OpenGL 3.x

Tags: opengl, java, graphics, lwjgl

I work in java with lwjgl3. I came across a strange artifact, the source of which I have not been able to determine for a very long time. I'm drawing a large surface. When I approach this surface and point the camera down, the lower part of the texture of my surface begins to tear and twitch as my camera moves.

To demonstrate the artifact, I will apply a chessboard pattern to the surface, which is drawn by shaders

This is what the surface looks like (just a wall):
[image]

I went to the surface and pointed the camera down (the lower part of the wall texture "broke" and moved):
[image]

If I put a png texture on the wall, the effect will be the same:
[image]

I have rechecked almost every part of my program where the problem could potentially be hiding. I tried to disable various functions in shaders and tried to play with opengl parameters, but it was useless. Has anyone encountered this? What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: When you say the surface is "large", can you tell us the coordinates of its corners? I'm suspecting we might be hitting floating point precision issues here.

Comment: Sure.
Lower left corner: (500, 0, -500)
Upper left corner: (500, 100, -500)
Lower right corner: (500, 0, 500)
Upper right corner: (500, 100, 500)
I tried to reduce the size of the surface, but it does not help